# Language String Failed to load : Recipients_failed

Tags: php, email

I have a script that sends a mail to validate a form made by a user. It's a professional application so the mail isn't a spam and the users are members of the company.

Now my PHPmailer() function bug once in two randomly. I would like technical help to see if I did something wrong in my PHP code. So first of all, this is what it should do:

1) the user end his form

2) he has to choose who will receive the email (between 3 choices, and he can cross the 3 checkboxes)

3) One mail will be sent to each person he checked, with a simple link to see the result of the form.

But most of the time, I have this error message:

```
 Language String failed to load:
 Recipients_failed [mail]

 *[Mail] = the email address*
```

The PHP script stops there, the page doesn't finish loading and the mail isn't send.

for the exemple, we'll say that in the first page we have [mail1], [mail2] and [mail3] who are 3 checkboxes.

Here is my code:

```
if(isset['[mail1]']){

    $mail = new PHPmailer();
            $mail->IsSMTP();
            $mail->IsHTML(true);
            $mail->Host=*;
            $mail->Port=*;
            $mail->From='no-reply@*.fr';
            $mail->FromName=*;
            $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';

            $mail->SMTPAuth=true;
            $mail->Username='no-reply@*.fr';
            $mail->Password='*';

            $mail->AddAddress([mail1]);

            $mail->Subject="*";

            $mail->Body = utf8_decode("*");  
if(!$mail->Send()){ 
            die($mail->ErrorInfo); 
        }

        $mail->SmtpClose();
        unset($mail);
}
```

I think that the code is ok because this works sometimes, but doesn't work sometimes... What should I do? Speak to OVH or there is something I did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your question has nothing to do with PHP.
The error message simply tells you that one of the recipients does not exist - this message does not come from php but from the SMTP server you are using.

However: I don't know why the server shows you an error message "no translation" - you should contact "OVH" and ask.

Comment: That's what I thought, but no answer since this morning so I tried to resolve the problem without them.